# Passing values from sub to function in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting a ByRef error and I just can't seem to figure it out.
The code is all written in the same module.

```
Sub GetTime(Labelname As Object)
Dim Hint, Mint, Sint As Integer
Dim time As String

Hint = CInt(Hour(Now))
Mint = CInt(Minute(Now))
Sint = CInt(Second(Now))

time = CorrectTime(Hint, Mint, Sint)

Private Function CorrectTime(Hours As Integer, Minutes As Integer, Seconds As Integer) As String
Dim HS, MS, SS As String

If Len(CStr(Hours)) = 1 Then
    HS = "0" & CStr(Hours)
Else
    HS = CStr(Hours)
End If

If Len(CStr(Minutes)) = 1 Then
    MS = "0" & CStr(Minutes)
Else
    MS = CStr(Minutes)
End If

If Len(CStr(Seconds)) = 1 Then
    SS = "0" & CStr(Seconds)
Else
    SS = CStr(Seconds)
End If

CorrectTime = HS & ":" & MS & ":" & SS
End Function
```

whenever i try to run the code, it gives me an error in

```
time = CorrectTime(Hint, Mint, Sint)
```

and the error type will be ByRef mismatch.

What am I not seeing that would solve this problem?

Comment: Btw, you should use `Long` instead of `Integer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common gotcha: `Dim Hint, Mint, Sint As Integer`

Here only `Sint` is an Integer, the other two variables are not declared with a type so default to `Variant`; when passed to a function expecting integers a mismatch error is thrown.

To correct:

`Dim Hint As Integer, Mint As Integer, Sint As Integer`

Comment: Wait, i've been declaring my variables like that in all my vba code.. Damn didnt know it had to be like that. Thanks a lot!